# Why aren't variable names converted to strings when using bracket notation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Considering: `var foo = {"5" : "ten", fighter : "Grohl"};`

Why is this the result?

```
foo[5];
"ten"

foo[1 + 4];
"ten"

foo[fighter];
ReferenceError: fighter is not defined
```

Of course, if I start with this: `var fighter = 'fighter';` then I get `Grohl` as expected.

My understanding is that when using bracket notation the expression inside the brackets are evaluated and converted to a string. So, in `foo[5]`, toString() is called on 5 in order to evaluate it to a string, which must be used with bracket notation. So my question is:

Why isn't the same luxury afforded to `fighter`? I know that foo['fighter'] works, but to know isn't to necessarily understand. I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Edit: Why *would* I expect this to be the case indeed. If fighter was a variable that held another string... say 'Dave', then how would javascript know whether I meant the reference to 'Dave' or if I wanted to convert fighter to the actual string, 'fighter'. Obviously javascript can't read my mind. Thanks to @DaveNewton and @pointy for the illumination.

Comment: Why *would* it be? How would you differentiate between a string and a variable holding a string? Magic?

Comment: `var foo = {5 : "ten", fighter = "Grohl"};` is simply a syntax error.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Thanks, error corrected.

Comment: @KeithGrout, it was still incorrect as you were using `=` instead of `:`. I corrected it. ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I see now that this would require javascript to perform a little bit of telepathy.

Comment: @KeithGrout I wasn't *just* trying to be a smart-ass, rather highlight that the values in `[]` are expressions, whether a string or numeric immediate, or a calculated value. It's because we can use calculated values we can do stuff like map a string to a function through an object, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because that's just not what the basic semantics of the language dictate. When you put `fighter` in brackets, you're saying "please evaluate this subexpression and use its value as the object property name".  The subexpression `fighter` is a reference to a symbol, not a string constant.

If you want to use an identifier's name as a literal property name, use the `.` operator:

```
foo.fighter
```

In your other examples, the same thing is going on. The subexpressions `5` and `1+4` are evaluated in exactly the same way they'd be evaluated elsewhere.  That is, consider:

```
var x = 1 + 4;
```

What do you expect that "x" will be?  OK, so then:

```
var x = fighter;
```

Clearly to expect that "x" would be the *string* "fighter" would be seriously weird; how would you ever reference a variable if the language did that?