# Javascript and using variables instead of strings in bracket notation

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I have a PHP script that takes a text list with a variable number of questions and generates HTML form code that looks like this.

```
What did you think of X?<br />
<input type="hidden" name="$survey[0][0]" value="What did you think of X?">
<input type="radio" name="$survey[0][1]" value="1">Didn't like it.
<input type="radio" name="$survey[0][1]" value="2">I was indifferent.
<input type="radio" name="$survey[0][1]" value="3">Liked it.
```

`$survey[n][0]` is the question, `$survey[n][1]` is the answer, and `n` is the variable number of questions.

To validate using Javascript, I have a loop that loops through the questions, and a loop inside it that makes sure each question has an answer. My problem is referencing the elements with `[]` in their names. Here's what I think is the relevant part of my code.

```
var formElements = document.forms["form"].elements;
var groupCount = document.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
var groupNdx = 0;
var groupName = "";
var btnCount = 0;
while (groupNdx < groupCount) {
  groupName = "'$survey[" + groupNdx + "][1]'";
  btnCount = formElements[groupName].length;
```

That last line doesn't work because `formElements[groupName]` is "undefined."
`formElements['$survey[3][1]']` works just fine, but that hardcodes the element's name, and I'd need to repeat the code for each question, and worse, it's a *variable* number of questions.

As I was typing, the Similar Questions sidebar suggested I read [Why aren't variable names converted to strings when using bracket notation in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134659/), so now I that's just how it is in Javascript.

But then what workaround would you suggest? I could just forget about validating with Javascript since I also validate the form with PHP, but I understand it's good practice to validate forms at both the client and server sides. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `'$survey[" + groupNdx + "][1]'` <- that is a rather strange key to use in an object, are you sure you're doing that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra set of single quotes that you shouldn't here:

```
groupName = "'$survey[" + groupNdx + "][1]'";
```

That adds single quotes into the key itself. Change that to:

```
groupName = "$survey[" + groupNdx + "][1]";
```

Notice that `x["'key'"]` is a different from `x['key']` in Javascript. The first has a key of `'key'` (including the quotes) while the second has just the string: `key`

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought the key itself had to have quotes around it. Marked as answered. :)